# Why <mx:XML> and <mx:XMLList> tags are obsoleted in Flex4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I was trying to implement menu bar control in my Flex application as follow:

```
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
    <mx:MenuBar id="myMenuBar2" labelField="@label">
        <mx:XMLList>
            <menuitem label="MenuItem A">
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem A-1" enabled="false"/>
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem A-2"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="MenuItem B"/>
            <menuitem label="MenuItem C"/>
            <menuitem label="MenuItem D">
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem D-1" 
                          type="radio" groupName="one"/>
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem D-2" 
                          type="radio" groupName="one"
                          selected="true"/>
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem D-3" 
                          type="radio" groupName="one"/>
            </menuitem>
        </mx:XMLList>
    </mx:MenuBar>
</mx:Panel>
```

But that will work only with the old library.

In Flex 4 we use following namespaces:

```
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

But `<mx:XML>` and `<mx:XMLList>` tags are not there.
However they are included in ActionScript 3.0.

Why they need this separation?
What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the namespace changed, XML and XMLList are now in the *fx* namespace